# How to check svn logs beween HEAD and last 10days

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can get svn logs between now and last 10days using date value.

```
 svn log -r{2019-02-01}:{2019-02-11} --xml --verbose > missing_logs.xml
```

but I don't want to hardcode date value in a script. Need svn log like below

```
 svn log -r{today-10}:HEAD --xml --verbose > missing_logs.xml
```

Comment: Can you use something like `date -v-10d "+%Y-%m-%d"` in backticks to generate the date you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone looking for an answer.

```
date1=$(date --date="10 days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d")
svn log -r{$date1}:HEAD --xml --verbose > missing_logs.xml
```